# WebSocket data consistency vs. latency

Tags: java, websocket, messaging, hana

Let's assume that I have a JavaScript front-end (Angular.js, for example), a Java-based back-end (Spring, running on Tomcat, for example) and a database management system (SAP HANA In-Memory, in my case). For example, I have graphs that can change relatively quickly.

I am wondering what an efficient and fast architecture could look like. Do you usually send a whole collection of objects to the UI or do you just send deltas?

In my case, data consistency on the UI is very important in order for the application to work properly, but low-latency as well, especially when it comes to data merges.

When it comes to consistency, I often tend to do a SELECT from the database on an insert and read the whole object collection again, but my concerns are that this does not scale.

Is there a generic approach to that problem or even existing frameworks?

Edit:
Currently, it is around 300 objects with a couple of integer attributes and cross-references that can change and rearrange in a millisecond time, but could go up to 10000 in the future. My challenge here is the communication between front-end and back-end, so the front-end always has a consistent data set in real-time.

Comment: So how much data are we talking about here?

Comment: @aksappy Currently, it is around 300 objects with a couple of integer attributes and cross-references that can change and rearrange in a millisecond time, but could go up to 10000 objects in the future. My challenge here is the communication between front-end and back-end, so the front-end always has consistent data in real-time.

Answer (score 1):

How close is the client to the server?  Is it a mile/km away or hundreds/thousands of miles away?  Is the client on the internet or is it on a high-performance VPN?  Are you close to the backbone or dozens of hops away?  You're not normally going to consistently get 1 millisecond latency on the web if you're trusting the general internet.

If you are on an internal company network and the client is physically close to the server, e.g., same machine, same local network, you can get single digit ms latency with WebSocket (I personally have gotten 3-4 ms across internal data centers at a big investment bank).

Don't optimize too early.  That's usually a bad thing.
Although with any high-performance UI, its always good to just send the deltas.

You may want to consider some sort of event mechanism to reduce your polling the data source.  Then you would only update the data when it actually changed.